# Adding the --command flag vs not adding

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

learning kubernetes from 0, Trying to find the difference between adding the --command flag to nod adding it to this command.

```
kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --command --restart=Never -- env
```

VS

```
kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- env
```

pretty much both worked for me, what am i missing ?

Wrote the output to yaml:

**With --command :**

```
- command:
  - env
  image: busybox
  name: busybox1
```

**Without --command :**

```
- args:
  - env
  image: busybox
  name: busybox
```

**what is the difference between args and command ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always look up by

```
kubectl run -h
```

Start the nginx container using the default command (i.e command defined in Docker container manifest) , but use custom arguments (arg1 .. argN) for that command.

```
  kubectl run nginx --image=nginx -- <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>
```

Start the nginx container using a different command and custom arguments.

```
  kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --command -- <cmd> <arg1> ... <argN>
```

If we compare with Docker:

Docker's `ENTRYPOINT` - executable invoked when the container is executed - maps to `command` in Kubernetes

Docker's `CMD` - arguments that get passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` maps to `args` - in Kubernetes

In your case it does not make any difference because you are not specifying any command actually (i.e. should be `--command ls` for example.

Comment: Really like the comparison, Thank you for your answer :).